# Inject list of Spring properties in annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to map REST endpoints dynamically to a RestController.
I'd like to configure the endpoints as properties.

My RestController looks like this

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {
    }

    @PutMapping("#{'${mapping}'.split(',')}")
    public String fooMapping(@RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {

        return "foo";
    }
}
```

The application.properties look like this

```
mapping=/mapping1,/mapping2,/mapping3
```

How do I inject the comma separated list into the annotation? The following hard-coded method does work.

```
@PutMapping(value = {"/mapping1", "/mapping2", "/mapping3"})
```

Comment: @PutMapping value takes only constant values. so you can't load its values from a property file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SpEL expressions works only with `@Value`annotation, but don't seems to work with `@RequestMapping` and related annotations. `@RequestMapping` only supports placeholders from properties.